# Post variable to http using curl[need help]

Tags: php

s,
I got an issue in which I want to send data to external system using curl
But i got struck in the middle in which I dont know how to send information like name and value to a specific URL.
Please help me to post blow name and values to a URL (Code below)

```
<input type=hidden name="Customer" value="v">
<input type=hidden name="cke" value="1">
<input type=hidden name="ownerid" value="2">
<input type=hidden name="overwrite" value="0">
<input type=hidden name="TriggerID" value="1951">
<input type=hidden name="PushExternal" value="1">
<input type=hidden name="rurl" value="http://www.runyourfleet.com">

<label for="City">City</label><input  id="City" maxlength="40" name="City" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="FirstName">FirstName</label><input  id="FirstName" maxlength="40" name="FirstName" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="LastName">LastName</label><input  id="LastName" maxlength="40" name="LastName" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="Email">Email</label><input  id="Email" maxlength="40" name="Email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: showing the form is irrelevant. doesn't matter how/where you get the data, what matters is how you take that data and feed it to curl, and what you're telling curl to do.

Comment: I want curl to post above form data to a specified URL. I have read the CURL function but dont know how to declare name and value in CURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://url/to/post/to';
$fields = [
    'Customer' => urlencode($_POST['Customer']),
    'cke' => urlencode($_POST['cke']),
    'FirstName' => urlencode($_POST['FirstName']),
    'LastName' => urlencode($_POST['LastName']),
    //etc
];

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
   $postFields .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
} 

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Is that the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: thanks Samantha this was what I was looking for
But how can I post constant with this Like Customer with Value "V"
and cke with Value "1"

Comment: actually I want to get information from customer and then send that information to Sales Fusion (CRM) and to our local email address.
So that is why I want to send constant and variables together.